# A function question; inverses

Tags: functions

If $f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x$ and $f$ and $g$ are continuous. Does it necessary follow that $g = f^{-1}$? Or do we need $g(f(x)) = x$ as well?

Comment: It depends whether $f$ has an inverse.

Comment: $f$ is only a left inverse of $g$ here. $g$ may not have a right inverse.

Comment: @toypajme, show me a counterexample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If "all $x$" means all real $x$, and "continuous" means "continuous on $\mathbb R$", then yes.  It's clear that $g$ is one-to-one.
$g({\mathbb R})$ is then an open interval.  Suppose that interval is not $\mathbb R$.
Consider e.g. the case where $g(x)$ increases to a finite value $b$ as $x \to +\infty$.
Then $\lim_{y \to b-} f(y) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} f(g(x)) = \infty$, contradicting
continuity of $f$ at $b$.

Comment: @sidth:What are the domains and ranges of $f$ and $g$? Are they defined on arbitrary sets $X,Y$ or are they defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @user64066, based on your comment there appears to be two cases. Could you show me both?

Comment: @Robert, your explaination is excellent. I understand it (only because I have some background in analysis). Is there a more fundamental explanation to someone of pre-calculus?